# Writing Decision Variables and Objective Function in PuLP Optimization Model

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

Disclaimer: I am a beginner at Python.

I have two LP problems that I need to solve using the PuLP library. The first model looks at all of my facilities and **total** customer demand, and decides which facilities to "open" to service this demand so that transportation costs are minimized from facility to customer. This first model will only consider overall demand from all products combined, not individual SKU demand. This model is working fine.

The output for the first model gave me:

1. Which warehouses we should open
2. How much TOTAL demand (all SKUs combined) each warehouse will service and for which customers

   For example:

   'Facility 5' services_('Apple') = 350.0
   'Facility 5' services_('Motorola') = 200.0
   'Facility 2' services_('Huawei') = 300.0
   'Facility 2' services_('Samsung') = 150.0

The second model/LP problem needs to detail down to the individual product (SKU) level and tell me specifically at which facility a SKU should be stocked and how much of an individual product (SKU) demand should be serviced from that facility.

I want the second model to only use the facilities that the first model's output recommended we open. For example, if the 1st model tells us to only open "Facility 2" and "Facility 5", then the second model should not allocate SKUs to any facility other than "Facility 2 and 5".

**QUESTION:**

**I need help writing the **decision variables** and **objective function** of the 2nd LP Problem/model**.** I need to write the decision variables/objective function in such a way that allows me to stock each SKU in a warehouse that is closest to most of the customers buying the SKU. Each SKU can only be stocked in 1 warehouse (or 2+ warehouses if a certain demand threshold is met). I am wanting the 2nd model to give me an output like this:

```
**1. STOCKING RECOMMENDATIONS:**  

'FAC 2': SKU 1: stock 200 lbs  
'FAC 2': SKU 2: stock 500 lbs  
'FAC 2': SKU 3: stock 0 lbs  


'FAC 5': SKU 1: stock 0 lbs  
'FAC 5': SKU 2: stock 0 lbs  
'FAC 5': SKU 3: stock 300 lbs  

**2. QTY SERV to CUSTOMER:**   

'FAC 2': SKU 1: service 150 lbs to 'Apple'  
'FAC 2': SKU 1: service 50 lbs to  'Samsung'    
'FAC 2': SKU 2: service 300 lbs to 'Huawei'  
'FAC 2': SKU 2: service 200 lbs to 'Apple'  
'FAC 2': SKU 3: service 0 lbs  


'FAC 5': SKU 1: service 0 lbs  
'FAC 5': SKU 2: service 0 lbs  
'FAC 5': SKU 3: service 100 lbs to 'Samsung'  
'FAC 5': SKU 3: service 200 lbs to 'Motorola'
```

........................................................................................................................................................

```
#Here's what I have so far for the second model:

**#lists/dictionaries, etc.**

Customer = ["Apple","Samsung","Huawei","Nokia","Motorolla"]  
Facility = ['Fac-1', 'Fac-2','Fac-3','Fac-4','Fac-5']  
Products = ['45906','48402','80591','102795','107275','128067','129522',]  
total_customer_demand={"Apple":80,"Samsung":270,"Huawei":250,"Nokia":160,"Motorolla":180}  
total_product_demand={'45906':143,'48402':131,'80591':194,'102795':105,'107275':80,'128067':138,'129522':149}  
Max_Supply={'Fac-1':950,'Fac-2':500,'Fac-3':500,'Fac-4':600,'Fac-5':700}  
fixed_cost={'Fac-1':1000,'Fac-2':1000,'Fac-3':1000,'Fac-4':800,'Fac-5':600}  

transportation_cost= {'Fac-1' : {"Apple":4,"Samsung":5,"Huawei":6,"Nokia":8,"Motorolla":10},  
                      'Fac-2' : {"Apple":6,"Samsung":4,"Huawei":3,"Nokia":5,"Motorolla":8},  
                      'Fac-3' : {"Apple":9,"Samsung":7,"Huawei":4,"Nokia":3,"Motorolla":4},  
                      'Fac-4' : {"Apple":3,"Samsung":4,"Huawei":8,"Nokia":4,"Motorolla":4},  
                      'Fac-5' : {"Apple":4,"Samsung":7,"Huawei":5,"Nokia":3,"Motorolla":2}  
                     }  

#Create a list within a list of customer demand for individual products  

indiv_product_demand=[  
    [10,25,26,30,52],#  Product# 45906  
    [14,63,9,39,6],# Product# 48402  
    [16,63,43,26,46], # Product# 80591  
    [4,33,43,13,12], #Product # 102795  
    [4,23,26,21,6], #Product # 107275  
    [18,48,17,9,46], #Product # 128067  
    [14,15,86,22,12] #Product # 129522  
                    ]  

#Make a dictionary out of the list w/in list above that contains customer demand for individual products    
product_demand = makeDict([Products,Customer],indiv_product_demand,0)  

.............................................................................................  
**#OUTPUT FROM 1ST MODEL (Recommended warehouses to use)**  
Establish Facility at site =  Fac-2  
Establish Facility at site =  Fac-5  

#Creating new list of "chosen facilities" which is output from the first model. This list will be used as a decision variable in LpProblem #2  

Tolerance = 0.0001  
chosen_facilities=[]  
for f in Facility:  
    if use_facility[f].varValue>Tolerance:  
        chosen_facilities.append(f)  

print(chosen_facilities)  
['Fac-2', 'Fac-5']  

#Creating a nested dict within a dict for LpVariable "qty_serv_customer"

qty_serv_customer = {} 

for f_ in Facility:
    item_f = {}
    for p_ in Products:
        item_p = {}
        for c_ in Customer:
            item_p[c_] = '' # Your value                                                                                                                      
        item_f[p_] = item_p
    qty_serv_customer[f_] = item_f

**#DECISION VARIABLES**

stock_at_WH = LpVariable.dicts("stock", chosen_facilities, 0, 1, LpBinary)  
qty_serv_customer = LpVariable.dicts("Service", [(cf,p,c) for cf in chosen_facilities for p in Products for c in Customer],0)  

**#SETTING THE 2ND LP PROBLEM**  
APTEW=LpProblem("Allocate_Product_to_each_Warehouse", LpMinimize)  

**#OBJECTIVE FUNCTION**  
APTEW += (lpSum(fixed_cost[f]*stock_at_WH[cf] for cf in chosen_facilities) +  
          lpSum(transportation_cost[f][c]*qty_serv_customer[cf][p][c] for cf in chosen_facilities for p in Products for c in Customer)) ''
```

'
.................................................................................................................................................................................................

#I know my objective function is incorrect. I get a "KeyError: 'Fac-2'" message when I run the code. I also think that there is an issue with the variable "qty_serv_customer". The decision variables and objective function may have to be re-written from scratch. Thanks in advance for any one who can help or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: You are trying to use 'Fac-2' as an index into an object that doesn't have it as a key. Remove terms of your objective function one at a time and see which is the problem. Then `print(object.keys())` where object is the offending item to find out why it's not setup the way you think.